# Concurrent Collection basic query

Tags: c#, concurrent-programming

I have the following scenario:
I have a Parallel.ForEach loop iterating over a collection of objects using a custom Partitioner. The partitioner takes a subset of 100 objects and sends them to a web service. The results returned need to be stored in a single collection. In other words all iterations of the Parallel.ForEach will write into a single collection.
Can I use a concurrent collection like ConcurrentBag for storing the results and be assured that the Parallel.ForEach iterations will not mutate the result in any way.

Thanks
Vikas

Comment: Yes the concurrent bag works perfect for this.

Comment: Thanks John for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address two parts of your question separately:

*Can I use a concurrent collection like ConcurrentBag for storing the results?*

Yes, `ConcurrentBag<T>` is specifically designed to support concurrent `Add`/`Remove`/iteration operations. If you're calling `Add` inside the `Parallel.ForEach` delegate body, all of the items you add are guaranteed to be stored - although their exact order is undefined.

*Can I ... be assured that the Parallel.ForEach iterations will not mutate the result in any way?*

This depends on *what it is exactly* you do inside your `Parallel.ForEach` delegate body. Like I said, if all you're doing there is storing the results in a `ConcurrentBag<T>` (via a call to `Add` somewhere in your `Parallel.ForEach` delegate - that's the most common use case), you're safe.

If you are performing more than one operation on `ConcurrentBag<T>` inside your `Parallel.ForEach` delegate (i.e. reading from `ConcurrentBag<T>` before you write to it), thread safety goes out the window.

Comment: We will just dump the result into the Concurrent Bag and once all iterations are complete, process the results in one go. So it is just a call to Add.

Comment: @Vikas, that's exactly what `ConcurrentBag<T>` is designed to do, so you're safe.